# Two cluster but only one nodepool?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I created two GKE clusters: c1, c2, but there are only one nodepool

```
gcloud container node-pools list
NAME          MACHINE_TYPE   DISK_SIZE_GB  NODE_VERSION
default-pool  n1-standard-1  100           1.9.7-gke.6
```

so they share the pool? i thought one cluster  has one pool..

Comment: Nope, two clusters can't share the pool. Are two clusters in the same project?

Comment: yes, in the same project

Answer (score 0):

This will list all node pools for each cluster

```
gcloud container node-pools list --cluster=c1
gcloud container node-pools list --cluster=c2
```

where c1 and c2 are the names of your clusters